# What is the C equivalent of python's help() and dir() functions?

Tags: c, linux

Objective :

- Get a list of all the available functions in a header file.
- Get a man-page like information of any function.

For example, I want a list of available functions in `<time.h>` and after that I want information of the function `time()`

I don't want to have to google the information of all these header files. With python I can just use the `dir()` and `help()` functions.

Comment: Nothing like this is built into the language, so we generally have to depend on external documentation or IDE-specific voodoo.

Comment: `grep` and `man`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja ```man time``` gives info on the time command and not the function ```time()``` Therefor this method is really a hit or miss. I think.

Comment: Best I can do for you: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono

Comment: @user4581301 **strike** By external documentations you mean just looking it up on the world wide web right?**strike** Okay. So nothing offline.

Comment: That or a book. I didn't have to look up the above link because I pretty much committed it to memory years ago. Do this stuff long enough and your head will be full of good documentation pages. Mind you, they have to be good documentation pages. Lot of utter crap on the Internet.

Comment: There's a man page for the function. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja yeah that kind of works if it is accessible through the terminal window. what's the man command for it? Or is it only available through a browser?

Comment: Here is no such thing in C. And I don't see how it would make sense. Unlike python, a C program needs to be compiled before it can be executed. So such a "built in" help feature would be too difficult to use. Instead a good external help-page is what you need

Comment: You need to know which section of the manual to look in.  The `time()` system call is usually in section 2, so `man -s 2 time` (or often `man 2 time`) will list the system call instead of the command.  Some functions are in section 3.  If the name is unambiguous, then it may be shown automatically (`man writev` for example); where the name is ambiguous, the command is shown in preference to the system call or function (`man write` for example).  There is no standard tool to report the functions declared by a header.  And the rat's nest of `#include` lines makes it hard to deduce what's there.

Comment: `man time.h`, `man 2 time`

Comment: @qrdl ```man time.h``` doesn't work but ```man 2 time``` does. thanks.

Comment: @qrdl: while `man time.h` may work on some systems, it does not work on all Unix-like systems (e.g. it does not work on macOS).  The question is tagged for Linux, so your comment may help there — I'm temporarily without access to my normal Linux boxes so I can't verify that.  (And a comment from the OP suggests that `man time.h` does not work for them.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess i'll just stick to the internet then.

Comment: @user17007422 cppreference provides a [downloadable archive for offline viewing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives). I always have a copy saved away on my laptop in case I find myself with an urge to code in a corner of the world without an internet connection.

Comment: That's reasonable if your machines are connected to the internet — the machines I use at work are not allowed to access outside resources.  You can use POSIX (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), Man7.org (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/) or Die.net (http://linux.die.net/man/) to get information for POSIX or Linux systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `man time.h` does work on Ubuntu, so it definitely works on some distros. `man7.org` has an entry for `time.h` - https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/time.h.0p.html , so I think it is mostly available

Comment: @qrdl: it's probably a case of YMMV — I'm giving a warning, not stating that you're wrong for all systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to python nature (being interactive) you can use function like dir() and help() but there no such thing in c (since it would not even make sense). to get an explanation about a function or a library:

since this is about the standard library take a look at:

- [the standard specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time)
- ask the manual with `man <function>` or `man <header>`
- if your on Unix/Linux go see [here for the unix standard specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.html)